# Fragment in ViewPager is blank onResume after scrolling back

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am using a `ViewPager` in my `MainActivity` with a `FragmentPagerAdapter` with four fragments. In the fragments data is displayed on a `ListView` with a custom adapter `NewsAdapter`. This data is loaded from the network and returned to the fragment by a `Loader`. Everything works on initial creation of the app, data loads onto the views without error. The problem I am having is when I scroll the `ViewPager` across two tabs `onDestroyView` is called in the fragment two tabs across and when I return to that fragment nothing is inflated except my `ProgressBar`, which is set to `View.GONE` when the `onLoadFinished` is called. This works as expected at first.

- I have noticed that even though `onLoadFinished` is being called when I return to the fragment, `mProgressBar.setVisibility.(View.GONE)` is not being executed.
- I have checked that `mAdapter` is not null in `onCreateView`, and is set to null `onDestroyView`, so I think the `Loader` is updating `mAdapter` when I'm returning to each fragment
- When I rotate the device `onDestroy` and `onResume` are called in `MainActivity`, but nothing is drawn on screen until I rotate again (back to vertical) then the fragments state is as expect until scrolling.
- I have tried changing `FragmentPagerAdapter` to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` with no change.
- I have cleared `mAdapter` and `mRootView` in `onDestroyView` to double check data is being passed in `onResume` fragment

Here is one of my fragments (they're all identical except for name and `Loader` id)

```
package com.example.android.greennewswire;

import android.app.LoaderManager; import android.os.Bundle; import android.support.annotation.Nullable; import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; import android.util.Log; import android.view.LayoutInflater; import android.view.View; import android.view.ViewGroup; import android.widget.ListView; import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class NewsFragmentSky extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<News>>{

    public NewsFragmentSky() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    //String object holding the network request URL to be passed into the Loader
    private static final String NEWS_REQUEST_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android";

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "NewsFragmentBBC";

    private NewsAdapter mAdapter;
    private View mRootView;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);

        //Create a LoaderManager and initialise the Loader
        LoaderManager loaderManager = getActivity().getLoaderManager();
        loaderManager.initLoader(4, null, this);

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        //TODO fix context problem!
        mAdapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<News>());
        ListView listView = (ListView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        boolean rootViewEmpty = (mRootView == null);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "rootView null? " + rootViewEmpty);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onCreateView called");
        return mRootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mRootView = null;
        boolean rootViewEmpty = (mRootView == null);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "rootView null? " + rootViewEmpty);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onDestroyView called.");
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onPause called.");
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onStop called.");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onResume called.");
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public android.content.Loader<ArrayList<News>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onCreateLoader called.");
        return new NewsLoader(getContext(), NEWS_REQUEST_URL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(android.content.Loader<ArrayList<News>> loader, ArrayList<News> newses) {
        mAdapter.addAll(newses);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        boolean adapterState = mAdapter.isEmpty();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onLoadFinished mAdapter null? " + adapterState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(android.content.Loader<ArrayList<News>> loader) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onLoaderReset called.");
        mAdapter.clear();
    } }
```

FragmentAdapter

```
package com.example.android.greennewswire;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.util.Log;

public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private static final String LOG_TAG = FragmentAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private Context mContext;

public FragmentAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "FragmentAdapter position: " + position);
        return new NewsFragmentBBC();
    } else if (position == 1) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "FragmentAdapter position: " + position);
        return new NewsFragmentReuters();
    } else if (position == 2) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "FragmentAdapter position: " + position);
        return new NewsFragmentRT();
    } else {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "FragmentAdapter position: " + position);
        return new NewsFragmentSky();
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 4;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return mContext.getString(R.string.category_bbc);
    } else if (position == 1) {
        return mContext.getString(R.string.category_reuters);
    } else if (position == 2) {
        return mContext.getString(R.string.category_rt);
    } else {
        return mContext.getString(R.string.category_sky);
    }
}
}
```

**Edit**: I have created a local variable for `LoaderManager` and `onDestroy` of the fragment, called `destroyLoader(i)` on it. This seems to work, when I scroll away from the fragment in the tab and back the fragment views are created with the data. I only add this as I'm unsure if this is best practice? I expect this is creating a new `Loader` and getting the data from the network each time the fragment is created, which really defeats the point of a `Loader` doesn't it. Am I correct in my assumption?

Edit2: I am now calling `mLoaderManager.initLoader(id, null, this)` in `onResume` method of each fragment. Checking Android Studio monitors network traffic graph as I scroll through the tabs data is only fetched once from the network. I still have an issue when the phone is rotated though, the views are not being created on first rotation (landscape), but on rotation back to portrait app behaviour is as expected. I'm going to look into my `MainActivity` lifecycle next.

Comment: As a simple fix, call `setMaxPageLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE);`  on your `ViewPager` to prevent your pages from being destroyed.

Comment: I will test this out thank you. I've edited my post with a solution which I've found, if you have any thoughts please let me know.